# Can't SSH to VirtualBox Ubuntu server from public IP

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, ssh

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 (latest version) on a virtual machine from my Windows machine and trying to set this up so I can access it from outside of my local network. I've been at this for a few hours and haven't had any success. 
I've got openssh installed, there are 2 adapters connected(one being NAT and the other a bridge adapter). I can connect just fine with the VM's local IP address and that's about it, whenever I try to connect to it from the public IP, it just times out. I do believe I port forwarded correctly, but I'm not 100% sure. 
Any tips or help is really appreciated.

Comment: what's the output of `nmap -PN {PUBLIC_IP}`, at least on one setup that i had similar to what you want, i get `22/tcp  open  ssh`

Comment: What's the output of `nc {PUBLIC_IP} 22` (replace 22 with the port number you use for SSH, and {PUBLIC_IP} with your public IP address).

Comment: @bistoco this is what I got http://prntscr.com/8u7qqp I suppose it's not correct, took a rather long time to run that as well

Comment: @Daniel I ran that, and oddly enough, printed out nothing, not sure if that's the desired output though

Comment: From *where* are you trying to connect with the public IP? Not all routers support [NAT loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback). Why do you have both NAT and bridged adapters? Some more details about the entire network topology (guest-host, host-LAN, LAN-WAN) would improve your question greatly.

Comment: @steeldriver I just tried connecting from someone else's computer, did not work either. And I have the NAT adapter so others can connect externally and the bridge adapter so I can connect to it locally, wasn't working any other way

Comment: I don't think it should be necessary to have different interfaces for LAN and external connections (and it complicates the routing). You should be able to EITHER (i) use a bridged guest-host adapter, and then forward from your residential LAN router direct to the VM's LAN IP; OR (ii) use a NAT guest-host adapter, and forward port(s) across BOTH the physical LAN router and the guest-host "virtual router" (via the VM's networking configuration settings).

Comment: as @steeldriver said, you don't need 2 interfaces, if you use the bridged adapter, all other machines in your lan will be able to see the guest by its local ip. My setup worked with a bridged adapter, a static ip for the guest. Port 22 open on guest. Reserved guest ip on router and router mapping 22 to guest static ip.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the fact that residential ISPs generally block ports such as 22, etc. You'll need to either use a different port, or ask your ISP if they can unblock the port.

Comment: I did change the port to 2222, although I did talk to my ISP and they assured me that port 22 is not blocked

Comment: @John Odd. I'll need to think about that one.